# What is **"put up a batch,"** and "to be right up to the mark"?

Tags: phrase-meaning

What is **"put up a batch,"** and "to be right up to the mark" in the text below?:

> News of his miracles got around by word of mouth among the poorer classes of town — he was not able to reach the better people (the "tony folks)", he called them) — but there was never a big enough sale to give Doc a steady income. For one thing, people thought there was more magic in Doc's touch than in his liniment, and, for another, the ingredients of Blackhawk cost so much that his profits were not very great. I know, because I used to go to the wholesale chemical company once in a while for him and buy his supplies. Everything that went into the liniment was standard and expensive (and well-known, not secret). A man at the company told me he didn't see how Doc could make much money on it at thirty-five cents a bottle. But even when he was very low in funds Doc never cut out any of the ingredients or substituted cheaper ones. Mrs. Willoughby had suggested it to him once, she told me, when she was helping him **"put up a batch,"** and he had got mad. "He puts a heap of store by that liniment **being right up to the mark,"** she said. Doc added to his small earnings, I discovered, by money he made gambling.

Answer (score 1):

Here "put up a batch" means simply to make a batch. The product was made in batches.

"Being right up to the mark" means that the product was honestly made as claimed.

Comment: @Jane, I need you to mark the answer as correct if you agree that it is correct.  I need the points so that I can help more people,